# How to prove columns of matrix $A$ are linearly independent $\implies$ $C$ must be invertible for the following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Suppose $A=BC$, where $B$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix .How to prove columns of $A$ are linearly independent $\implies$ $C$ must be invertible?

In my opinion, I feel like we have to express the reasoning in summation. But is there a way to reason by wording (/theorem)?

Answer (score 2):

Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, $A$ has rank $n$. On the other hand, $\operatorname{rank}(BC) \le \operatorname{rank}(C)$, so $\operatorname{rank}(C) = n$. Since $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $n$, $C$ is invertible.